# Converting $\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}{2}$ into $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fractions

A few days ago I had a quiz question on calculating the sine of $15^\circ$. Using the half-angle identity for sine, I did the following:
$$\sin15^\circ=\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}{2}$$

But the lecturer give this:
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

This is also the first answer given by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%2015).

So my question is: how does one convert between the two forms?
$$\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

**Edit:** and why would one prefer the second over the first, if the the first is so straightforward to reach?

Comment: Observe,$$(\sqrt{3}-1)^2=2(2-\sqrt{3})$$

Comment: I think you have improved your question, and so I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{3}+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks. I should've asked _why_ the lecturer and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin+15) would opt for the second form, when it seems to require more steps if one uses the half-angle identity.

Comment: Please refrain from answering very low quality PSQs, as written in the Enforcement of Quality Standards.

Comment: Please refer to [the guidelines for enforcing quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Thank you.